# Sending message through whats App without user interaction in android

Tags: android, sharing, social-media

I wanted to know how I can send text to specific whats app contacts without user interaction. I found some code to view a specific contact, but not to send data & some code which opens the specific chat with message. But all contains user interaction so all i want to know is, is it possible to share a message on whats app without user interaction?

Comment: you cannot send the message without user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, i found that sending message through what's app application without user interaction is not possible. What's app sharing popup or sharing dialog always shown to user's screen as per my R&D.

Comment: you can do using Twilio API.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, the only way you 'should' do this is with a [ShareIntent](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely send msg to WhatsApp, without using API.

1. You have to be logged in in your what's app account in WhatsApp web.
2. You first have to install pywhatkit library

```
pip install pywhatkit 

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg('number to the person with STD code','message',19,26)

#19 = time in hour 
#26 = time in second
```

then just don't close the IDE, it will send the message directly!